# What is the software different between Apple Lisa and first Macintosh?

Tags: mac, software, history

Lisa is released before Macintosh, but LOTS of books mention that the development of Macintosh involve a lot of effort and innovation. So, what are the Apple Lisa and Macintosh software major different? Also, is this the Lisa is the first Apple desktop using a mouse? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Apple had a mouse for the Apple II line although I'm not sure if it overlapped with the Lisa and Mac.

The first Lisa had its own operating system which used an early version of Bill Atkinson's quickdraw routines, had overlapping windows, pull down menus although if memory serves it had a document model more like OpenDoc than what the Mac had a bit later.

After the Mac came out in 1984 the Lisa was rebranded "Macintosh XL" and it used an early version of the Macintosh OS until it was phased out.

In short, the Lisa was the bridge between the ideas that Jobs, Atkinson and others had seen at Xerox PARC and the Mac.

Here's an excellent history: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_lisa